# identify GPS mobile phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova, gps, phonegap-plugins

I am using the plugin geolocation iOS phonegap and everything seems to work very well, iOS I identify if the GPS is enabled (default) this way:

```
  function success(pos) {
    $scope.latitud = pos.coords.latitude
    $scope.longitud =  pos.coords.longitude;
  };

  function error(err) {
    alert("El servicio de GPS en tu dispositivo esta desactivado.");
  };

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success,error);
```

If I can not get latitude and longitude, logically, I determine that the PS is in IOS desativado and this works very well, but not Android. I wanted to know if anyone has been able to create an option or find an option to identify whether the GPS is on or not, Since I imagine that mine is not the best way to determine.

Comment: the alert in your error callback isn't called in Android when GPS is OFF ?

Comment: yes, Android does not send the alert

Comment: Try this http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#geolocation.getCurrentPosition

Comment: seems to be the same as I do, there are many functions that you say?

Comment: This is weird because I'm using watchPosition (instead of getCurrentPosition ) and I have an alert when GPS is OFF. But it should be the same for both , I don't understand

Comment: Android has brought several problems xD I'll see what I can do, if you notice something !, thanks for your help